# When using std::map should I overload operator== for the key type?

Tags: c++, stl

The std::map should not have duplicated keys so how does it knows I have a duplicated key when I have a custom type, do I need do overload overload operator==? Or it will be implicitly created?

According to the documentation I only need the operator< but this is not enough to maintain the keys' unicity.

Consider this example:

```
class MyType{
public:
  MyType(int newId){
    id = new int;
    *id = newId;
  };
  ~MyType{
    delete id;
  }
private:
  int* id;
};

int main(){
  std::map<MyType,int> myMap;

  std::pair<std::map<MyType,int>::iterator,bool> ret;
  ret = myMap.insert ( std::pair<MyType,int>(myType(2),100) );

  if (!ret.second) {//now how can he knows that?
    std::cout << "element already existed" << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your type `MyType` violates Rule of Three/Five. There is no need for dynamic allocation here.

Comment: I know that just used as an example. This is not the point here...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`std::map` does not care about literal *unicity* of the keys. It cares about keys *equivalence*. The keys `a` and `b` are equivalent by definition when neither `a < b` nor `b < a` is true.

Note also that `std::map` does not directly use `operator <`. `std::map` does not know anything about `operator <`. Instead `std::map` uses the comparison predicate, whose type is specified as the third parameter of `std::map` template. The default value of that parameter is `std::less`. Implementation of `std::less` delegates the comparison to `operator <` (unless specialized differently). This is how `operator <` comes into play. But you can always supply your own predicate which will not necessarily use `operator <`.

But in any case the key moment here is that `std::map` uses an ordering "less" comparison and only "less" comparison. It does not need and does not care about any "equality" comparisons.

Meanwhile, `std::unordered_map` would be a different story. It relies on non-ordering "equality" comparison specified by a predicate. By default it is `std::equal_to`. Implementation of `std::equal_to` delegates the call to `operator ==` (unless specialized differently).

Comment: It should be noted that C++20 removes the delegated `map` comparison operators with the exception of the equality operator and replaces them with the spaceship operator `<=>`.

Comment: @David G: What exactly are you referring to? As far as I can see, in C++20 `std::map` still uses `std::less` and the main `std::less` template still uses `<`. It is true that in C++20 the `<` can be implicitly derived from `<=>`, but that is a different topic, not related to `std::map`.

Comment: What I'm referring to is that the suite of comparison operators (apart from the equality operator) that `std::map`used prior to C++20 (e.g. `template< class Key, class T, class Compare, class Alloc > bool operator!=( const std::map<Key,T,Compare,Alloc>& lhs, const std::map<Key,T,Compare,Alloc>& rhs );` is now subsumed into the spaceship operator for the map's value type, and operators are subsequently _synthesised_ from it. `std::less` is going to be using `<` unless specified as a template parameter. It's just an FYI for people who might be surprised by the new behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

operator < is enough. Equality can be checked by testing a < b and b < a both returning false.

Comment: Oh of course yes thanks, so even if I implemented operator== myself it will be ignored?

Comment: Yup, the implementation of map only uses <

Comment: @Jasper: actually, _equality_ is _never_ checked! What is checked is _equivalence_! It doesn't matter? Well, consider a key consisting of a `std:pair<int, int>` where only the `first` component is used for the ordering comparison: the objects may not be equal but they could still be considered equivalent.

Comment: Of course, the thing that will be checked is what your operator < defines. (whether you name it equality or equivalence). Equivalence is indeed a better name in your example with the pair<int, int>

Answer (score 2):

You should overload `operator<`.

The `std::map` will compare keys using 
`!(a < b) && !(b < a)` as a test for uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

The order associative containers only use a strict weak order to identify they keys. They won't use `operator==()`. The only comparison used to locate objects is the third template argument to `std::map<K, V, Compare, Allocator>`.

The comparison is used to group keys into equivalence sets. Two keys `k1` and `k2` are considered to be equivalent if neither `k1` is smaller than `k2` nor `k2` is smaller than `k1`:

```
bool equivalent = !(k1 < k2) && !(k2 < k1);
```

Of course, the associative containers will actually use something more like

```
!predicate(k1, k2) && !predicate(k2, k1)
```